# Get the html of a TR

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html in the format of tr td .Now i want to get the html of tr whose id is table_structure.And i want to get the very specific html of the id.I want to get the last 3 td html by using jquery .How can we get this .Please help me

**HTML :**

```
 <table id="chargeshtml" style ="display:none">
    <tr class="inputstr">
        <td style="font-size:12px">Code</td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="code" name="code" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="charges_id" name="charges" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Adt Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="adt_charges" name="adt_charges" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Chd Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="chd_charges" name="chd_charges" value=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="chktr">
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" name="chk" id="chk" value="Checked" >Cheked </br>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

On the click of chk i want to get the this HTML from te above

```
<td style="font-size:12px">Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="charges_id" name="charges" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Adt Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="adt_charges" name="adt_charges" value=""/>
        </td>
        <td style="font-size:12px">Chd Charges </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" id="chd_charges" name="chd_charges" value=""/>
        </td>
```

Comment: row html: `$('#table_structure').prop('outerHTML')`

Comment: td html: `$('#table_structure td').slice(-3).map(function () {
    return this.outerHTML;
}).get().join('')`

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w9ecU/3/

Comment: The update says, that you want the last *6* cells. Is this correct?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try,

```
$('#table_structure td:gt(1)').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).html());
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hSXE9/)

```
var xHtml = $('#table_structure td:gt(1)').map(function(){
                return $(this).html();
            }).get().join('');
```

### [DEMO I](http://jsfiddle.net/hSXE9/1/)

---

As per your new request and your new html structure I just written some code and framed a demo, just check that [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hSXE9/2/) and [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/hSXE9/4/)

Answer (score 7):

You can use `slice(-3)` to get the last three TD's regardless of how many there are

```
$('#table_structure td').slice(-3);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4uCys/1/)

**EDIT:**

Based on the edited question, you can get the markup like this

```
$('.inputstr td').slice(-6).map(function() { 
    return this.outerHTML; 
}).get().join('');
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tC4z8/1/)

Comment: suppose, I want to select from 2nd last and 3 td, how to do?

Comment: @C-link - Something like `.slice(2, -2)`

Answer (score 2):

Just try with:

```
$('#table_structure td:gt(-4)');
```

It returns last 3 `td` elements in the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/arKSB/

Comment: amazed gt() also accepts minus... +1

Comment: It's quite confusing that it should be `-4` not `-3` but if we set `-1` it returns nothing so we have to use -1 more.

Comment: can you explain a little what gt  do??

Comment: @EhsanSajjad https://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/

Answer (score 0):

Check out this fiddle i hope its what you are looking for.

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PyKCT/)

```
var html = $('table').find($('tr#table_structure')).html();
console.log(html);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the last six `<td>`s as jQuery objects, use @adeneo's answer. If you need the HTML as string, you can use this (w/o jQuery):

```
/* mark-up of last six cells (including '<td>') as string: */
html = Array.prototype
          .slice(document.getElementById('table_structure').cells, -6)
          .map(function(td) { return td.outerHTML(); })
          .join('');
```

(Edit: Replace `-3` with *`-6`*, since the updated question suggests this.)